# Defining Excel ranges via reference to other cells

Tags: excel, reference, range

I'm trying to create a reference to an array of cells in column A, but instead of a reference of the form `A1:A100` I seek to make a reference of the form `A[value at cell B1]:A[value at cell B2]`. Does Excel support this method of referencing cells?

Much gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create dynamic cell addresses in formulas you can use:

```
=indirect("A" & B1 & ":A" & B2)
```

This also works for addressing cells on another worksheet.
Also note that any part of a cells address can be a variable. (i.e. the sheetname, the column or the row)

Indirect is especially useful in that it protects the address even if the worksheet referenced is deleted, typically producing a #Ref!

Comment: Is there some reason that this doesn't work with a lookup? I'm trying something like `=table1!INDIRECT("$G" & A2 & ":$G$2452")<>""`, but Excel sees this as erroneous. Thanks!

Comment: should be =INDIRECT("table1!$G" & A2 & ":$G$2452")<>""